Will two inlets into a 4-in corrugated water pipe handle more water than one
I have a small pond on the one side of my house and I plan to run a 4-in corrugated pipe to the catch Basin at the road which is 500 ft away and the fall will probably be close to 3 ft and I have a 21 in catch basin at the other end that I'm going to run the 4 inch corrugated pipe out of and I'm wondering if I put two outlets out of that 21 inch catch Basin and run it into the same 4-in corrugated pipe if it will flow more water to the catch basin at the road instead of just one Outlet out of the 21 inch catch basin

Any pipe of a certain diameter can only flow so much water.  Two outlets will not increase the flow.  It might have other benefits, like spreading the flow from one point.

0.6% is just above the minimum slope for a pipe, and a 4" corrugated pipe at that slope is not going to have much of a flow capacity to begin with.  Whether you have two inflows into that pipe, or a split outflow from it, the bottleneck will be that 4" pipe at 0.6% slope.
(Also, full flow at that slope is only 1 ft/s, below the 3 ft/s that is typically considered sufficient to prevent sediment deposit.)
